# Django STATIC_URL on requests

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, doccano

I have this Django project (https://github.com/chakki-works/doccano) that I'm trying to deploy using `Apache` + `mod_wsgi`.

I set up my `.conf` file to work as a Daemon proccess where application is served under an alias (`/doccano`) path:

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/doccano/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/doccano/app/staticfiles/

WSGIDaemonProcess doccano user=apache group=apache python-home=/var/www/doccano/env
WSGIProcessGroup doccano

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias /doccano /var/www/doccano/app/app/wsgi.py
```

The application was doing fine while static files were not being served as I mapped /doccano alias:

[image: Main page request]
[image]

The `Alias /static/ /var/www/doccano/app/staticfiles/` fixed static files problem.

But I still want to serve other applications in this server, so mapping `/static/` may not be a good idea.

So I want to know what is the best approach for this situation. I was trying to add `/doccano/` at the beginning of the static requests url setting `STATIC_URL=/doccano/static/` but I think this property is not for doing this type of setting.

Comment: Are you adding this inside <VirtualHost> directive?

Comment: Sure `<VirtualHost *:80>`